# Android Kotlin: Having a global Context object for all activities (best practice)

Tags: android, kotlin, static, global-variables, android-context

I have a global app settings class as follows:

```
class AppSettings : MultiDexApplication() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
        resourses = applicationContext.resources
        outputPathCache = cacheDir.absolutePath
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: AppSettings
            private set

        val context: Context
            get() { return activityContext.get()!! }

        lateinit var activityContext: WeakReference<Context>

        var database: SQLiteDatabase? = null

        var resourses: Resources? = null
            private set

        lateinit var dialog: AlertDialog

        const val defLanguage = Enum.Language.ENGLISH
        const val defIdLanguage = Enum.LanguageId.ENGLISH
        const val screenshotFilename = "xxx"

        const val actionBarTitleColor = "#0D0D0D"
        const val footerColor = "#8a8a8a"
        const val activityBackground = "#ffffff"

        ... whatever
    }
}
```

And as you see I have a static Context variable as follows:

```
lateinit var activityContext: WeakReference<Context>
```

(I use WeakReference so the IDE doesn't complain about memory leaks).

And I have a constant Context like the next:

```
val context: Context
                get() { return activityContext.get()!! }
```

I assign a value for the first time to activityContext in SplashActivity as follows (I do this because the first activity is a OnBoarding class that doesn't inherit from BaseActivity):

```
AppSettings.activityContext = WeakReference(this)
```

The same in BaseActivity onCreate (most of my activities inherit from this class):

```
AppSettings.activityContext = WeakReference(this)
```

And then, in any activity which extends BaseActivity I can use the context simply like this:

```
AppSettings.context
```

For the activities that doesn't inherit from BaseActivity I just initialise the context to be used in the activity in the same way as in Base, so I can always get it as "AppSettings.context".

The reason of not simply using "this" in all activities to get context (or to use any sort of Context creation in Base) is that I'm using MVVM and there are classes outside activities (like ViewModel) with methods that may need a context, and I just don't wan't to pass it as a parameter (this is why I'm expecting to have a global context that can be accessed anywhere).

Although I have just finished and I haven't fully tested yet, it is apparently working great, but I wonder to know if this is the recommended way to deal with this, or if there is a better approach to have a global Context.

Comment: "I'm using MVVM and there are classes outside activities (like ViewModel) with methods that may need a context" -- inject one using your dependency inversion framework. Or, use `AndroidViewModel`, which provides access to the `Application` (an implementation of `Context`). "but I wonder to know if this is the recommended way to deal with this" -- no. "if there is a better approach to have a global Context" -- having a global anything is usually bad for testability. But, `Application` is itself a global `Context`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @CommonsWare. I've just migrated to MVVM, so still pending things to do. I work with dependency injection in C#, but I don't have much knowledge on dependency inversion in Android yet. Any framework you can recommend? Any site where I can get some guidelines on how to start with DI on Android?

Comment: "Any framework you can recommend?" -- Dagger with Hilt is the official recommendation from Google, and for larger projects IMHO it's probably the best option. For small projects, IMHO Koin is easier. There is also Kodein and probably others that I am forgetting. FWIW, I cover Koin in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-di-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack). Google has [docs on Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android). I am sure that there is more written on the subject as well.

Comment: Thank you very much @CommonsWare. I'll start reading on them.

Comment: BTW @CommonsWare, and talking about best practices, what do you think about having a settings class with static variables as mine to store the whole app configuration?

Comment: IMHO, it hampers testability.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246485/discussion-between-diego-perez-and-commonsware).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways to achieve that, but I believe the most encouraged by google is with the dependency injection library [dagger-hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android), which isn't hard to set-up, but saves a lot of time and prevents possible memory-leaks.
In order to inject context into any class later you just need to do:

```
class ExampleClass @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext val context: Context) {}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @JustSightseeing. I'll read about it and I'll try to implement it :)

Comment: If you will have any problems let me know :D